# Looking for a good C++ based RSS API

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, rss

I tried http://code.google.com/p/feed-reader-lib but holy cow, talk about difficult to build. It has a nightmare of dependencies on Xerces and Xalan, both of which seem to be choking under the new VisualStudio 2010 C++ compiler. I've wasted hours trying to build this thing which is a shame. Does anyone have anything a little easier to hit the ground running with?

Comment: Create a virtual machine on your box and use Linux. All those libraries are pretty standard on most distros. On Debian or Ubuntu you would be up and running in under an hour.

Comment: Wow really? My entire project is build in VisualStudio .NET. Here's a better idea. Maybe the people who made Xerces/Xalan can come up with a better build system that doesn't require jumping through hoops. This is 2010. For open source to be useful it should take minutes to download and build.

Comment: Furthermore, why does Xalan-C say it's for Xerces 2.7, when Xerces is already at 3.2?? What's that all about?

Comment: Xalan-C development has slowed to a trickle.  I think there is only one person developing it.  The fist time I checked the release version was 1.10 with the next version due soon, this was 5 years ago and while code is being added since there is no sign of a release.  I had to take a snapshot of svn with no labels to get it build with VC2005.  Currently we are looking for a new XSTL processor to move to I don't think xalan can be relied on for c++ development.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question:
[Recommendations: Easy To Use/Low Dependency C/C++ RSS Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459874/recommendations-easy-to-use-low-dependency-c-c-rss-library)